# VScode showing files that doesn't exist

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am very bad at English so I'll make this as short and simple as possible. I use a mac, and I was editing files in my VScode workspace, then I decided to be very extra and make a git repo on the file. Then I don't want it anymore so I deleted the `.git` folder. But on VScode I can see a lot of useless files that start with a `.`. But when I check the finder I can't see any of the `.` files. For example, I have a file called index.html before I init the git, but after I delete the `.git` folder I can still see `.index.html` file in file explorer in VSCode, but it doesn't show the `.index.html` in folder(I have show hidden file on). I very want to know how to remove it because it is very annoying. [VScode file explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUOym.png)

Comment: Set Finder to show hidden files.

Comment: i have it on but it still doesn't show it

Comment: You can check all files including hidden ones in terminal/shell using command `ls -a`. And to remove the files you can try to operate in VSCode explorer directly.